# Zend Framework: passing GET params to paginator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I'm trying to finish search form and one of it parts is pagination. The problem is next:
I don't know how to pass GET params to paginator links (ex: /page/2?search=query).
I have created 'controls.phtml' in application/scripts directory and in Bootsrap added

```
Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('controls.phtml');
```

and render paginator in view:

`echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Elastic', 'controls.phtml');`

Could somebody write step-by-step actions I need to do to decide this problem? (With ZF I'm 2nd day only)

Answer (score 0):

I would do more on the Controller and just pass the `$paginator` itself to the view.  Something like this in your Controller:

```
Zend_Paginator::setDefaultScrollingStyle("Elastic");
Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial("controls.phtml");

$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
$paginator->setPageRange(5);
//this is where you collect the GET param and use as parameter.
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $this->getRequest()->getParam("page", 1));

$this->view->paginator = $paginator; //pass it from Controller into View
```

Then in the View code:

```
<?= $this->paginator; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you're not going to send the query parameters to the paginator, you're going to send them to the [paginator adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html). Then the selected adapter will perform any actions required... *database querying or parsing an array.*.. Then you'll pass the database adapter into the paginator.

Here is a controller action that either builds a paginator or redirects based on a get query:

```
public function displayAction()
    {
        //get all parameters from requested url
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        //build switch based GET query
        switch ($request) {
            //if ?query=value
            case (isset($request['query'])):
                //model to use for database query
                $model = new Music_Model_Mapper_Track();
                //paginator adapter to use
                $adapter = $model->fetchPagedTracks(null, $request['query']);
                //intiate new paginator
                $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
                //provide paginator page values
                $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20)->setPageRange(5);
                //?page=1 is default
                $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page', 1);
                //current page number
                $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
                //pass paginator to view
                $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
                break;
            //if ?id=value
            case (isset($request['id'])):
                $this->_forward('artist', null, null, array('id' => $request['id']));
                break;
            //if neither query value present. Should never get here.
            default:
                $adapter = $model->fetchPagedTracks();
                //[...]
                break;
        }
    }
```

I use a modified adapter for my paginator adapter. It is extended from the DbTableSelect adapter and simply substitutes a mapper in for a database table:

```
class Music_Model_Paginator_Track extends Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect
{
    /**
     * Override getItems() to use mapper model instead of database table
     */
    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        $rows = parent::getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage);

        $albums = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $album = new Music_Model_Mapper_Track();
            $albums[] = $album->createEntity($row);
        }
        return $albums;
    }
}
```

in that mapper I use the paginator adapter in exactly the same way a default adapter would be used:

```
/**
     * Creates Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect object,
     * based on artist_id or query string.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @param string $query
     * @return Music_Model_Paginator_Track
     */
    public function fetchPagedTracks($id = null, $query = null)
    {
        //if $id is not null where=$id
        if (!is_null($id)) {
            $select = $this->getGateway()->select();
            $select->where('track.artist_id = ?', $id);
        }
        //if $query is not null join on the artist table and query track title and artist name for match.
        if (!is_null($query)) {
            $select = $this->getGateway()
                ->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
            $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
            $select->join('artist', 'artist.id = track.artist_id');
            $select->where("track.title LIKE '%$query%'");
            $select->orWhere("artist.name LIKE '%$query%'");
        }
        //default select query if $id and $query are null, appended to query otherwise.
        $select->order('track.artist_id ASC');
        $select->order('track.album_id ASC');
        $select->order('track.track_number ASC');
        //instantiate paginator adapter
        //$adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect() would also work
        $adapter = new Music_Model_Paginator_Track($select);
        //return paginator adapter
        return $adapter;
    }
```

and finally the view is nothing special:

```
<div><?php
echo $this->paginationControl(
        $this->paginator, 'Sliding', '_paginatorControl.phtml'
)
?></div>
//[..]
```

For some of the adapters(in certain situations) you may have persist your query values with [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html) or [Zend_Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.introduction.html) to passed back into the url.

Hope this helps.